# How to achieve this effect where text lightens an image?

Tags: text, effects, blend-modes

[image: Verge Video]

What kind of effect is this? I know it's some kind of blending but I can't figure out what kind.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple white text with `overlay` as blend mode:

[image]

Comment: I think there's some kind of gradient in there too, if you look at the A in astronaut for example. And can't decide if there's a grunge effect, or just low quality jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop Above layers (it might say "normal")
or illustrator under the appearance panel
or inDesign listed as "effects" (aka effects panel)

look for "overlay" or "multiply" in those sections(respectively).

I would also look into clipping masks for each. You might have better results having one bottom layer and then make a clipping mask with the text and adjust the color that way. It looks like the text is an overlay with a brighter lighting which could be just one of the other effects applied to it or it could be a more complex thing like a clipping mask.